# Python / Pandas Dataframe change specific value

Tags: pandas

I have a column in DataFrame a `Start_Time (datatype: Object)` with values as :-

```
6:00:00
7:00:00
8:01:00
```

and want to change it to

```
6:30:00
7:30:00
8:30:00
```

Comment: So are these strings or datetime objects? post raw data and code to reproduce your df

Comment: These are strings .. i am extracting df from a csv file.

Comment: Well the simplest thing would be to just do `df['Date'].str.split(':').str[0] + ':30:' + df['Date'].str.split(':').str[-1]` but are you intending to keep the `dtype` as `str` or some `datetime` variant?

Comment: will try this and the one below as well.. I would not mind if datatype is changed to datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
print df
         a
0  6:00:00
1  7:00:00
2  8:01:00

b = pd.to_datetime(df['a']) + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30) 
print b
0   2016-02-17 06:30:00
1   2016-02-17 07:30:00
2   2016-02-17 08:31:00
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print b.dt.time
0    06:30:00
1    07:30:00
2    08:31:00
Name: a, dtype: object

print b.dt.time.values
[datetime.time(6, 30) datetime.time(7, 30) datetime.time(8, 31)]
```

But if you need reset `minutes`:

```
print df
         a
0  6:00:00
1  7:00:00
2  8:01:00

df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a']) 
print df 
                    a
0 2016-02-17 06:00:00
1 2016-02-17 07:00:00
2 2016-02-17 08:01:00

df['a'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour)) 
print df
                    a
0 2016-02-17 06:00:00
1 2016-02-17 07:00:00
2 2016-02-17 08:00:00

b = df['a'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30) 

print b.dt.time
0    06:30:00
1    07:30:00
2    08:30:00
Name: a, dtype: object

print b.dt.time.values
[datetime.time(6, 30) datetime.time(7, 30) datetime.time(8, 30)]
```

Comment: this is giving ambiguous results for time having two digits like 10:00:00 gives 01:30:00 instead of 10:30:00